# Dax measure (add new columns) not showing total in table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I use DAX to add two new columns "netWeight_Shipped" and "NetWeight_notShipped" based on existing column "NetWeight_Total" and groupped by "BatchNo" and filtered by OutStockTransactionID as below:

--New column

```
 NetWeight_Shipped = 
                        CALCULATE(
                            SUM(Fact_ShippingKPI[NetWeight_Total])
                            ,ALLEXCEPT(Fact_ShippingKPI,Fact_ShippingKPI[BatchNo])
                            ,Fact_ShippingKPI[OutStockTransactionID] <> 0
                        )
```

--New column

```
NetWeight_notShipped = 
                CALCULATE(
                    SUM(Fact_ShippingKPI[NetWeight_Total])
                    ,ALLEXCEPT(Fact_ShippingKPI,Fact_ShippingKPI[BatchNo])
                    ,Fact_ShippingKPI[OutStockTransactionID] = 0
                )
```

Then put those columns on table as the screenshot. However, two new columns not showing total values in table.

[image]
What should I change to have total values for those new columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display total values in the table, you should create and use two new measures "netWeight_Shipped" and "NetWeight_notShipped" based on the existing columns, but not two new columns.
[image]

-- New measure

```
NetWeight_Shipped = CALCULATE(
                        SUM(Fact_ShippingKPI[NetWeight_Total])
                        ,ALLEXCEPT(Fact_ShippingKPI,Fact_ShippingKPI[BatchNo])
                        ,Fact_ShippingKPI[OutStockTransactionID] <> 0
                    )
```

-- New measure

```
NetWeight_notShipped = CALCULATE(
                           SUM(Fact_ShippingKPI[NetWeight_Total])
                           ,ALLEXCEPT(Fact_ShippingKPI,Fact_ShippingKPI[BatchNo])
                           ,Fact_ShippingKPI[OutStockTransactionID] = 0
                       )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply aggregation to your column to see the total value below. Look at this image I have added the same column twice and for the first one, there is no total value. But for the second one, there is a total. This is only for the aggregation I applied to the second column but not to the first column-

[image]

Comment: I have tried to apply aggregation Sum function as @mkRabbany method, then wrong results for both individual and total values.

Comment: Can you provide sample raw data and your expected output from them?

Comment: Sorry I am new here, how to provide raw data? or provide the .pbix file?

Comment: You can provide the pbix file link (google drive), but with sample data. Never share your real data! to anyone.